# Add new parameter into url

Tags: php

I'm developing a website using html php. The website has two languages the user can choose by clicking on a link in the header.

The code is

```
<a href="?lang=eng">English</a>/<a href="?lang=arb">عربي</a>';
```

When the url become 
`www.example/qoustion?lang=arb&paramt=1.php`
and the user click on another language the url becomes 
 `www.example/qoustion?lang=arb.php` 
so the second parameter disappear

I tried this but every time is add lang  parameter in url but the old lang is work :(

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
print ' <a href="'.$url.'?lang=eng">English</a>/<a href="'.$url.'?lang=arb">عربي</a>';?>
```

I want to substract old lang every time the user change the language

Comment: I hope you aren't including dynamically `lang.php` with `$_GET`.

Comment: I'd suggest cookies and sessions are probably the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
....
$oldLang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : null;
....
?>
<a href="?lang=eng&oldLang=<?php echo $oldLang;?>">English</a>/<a href="?lang=arb&oldLang=<?php echo $oldLang;?>">عربي</a>';
```